# How to make Labels in RecycleView change size according to texture size during runtime?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have a `RecycleView` which consists of labels and a `MDSlider` which I use to change `font_size` of those labels during runtime. I'm wondering if it's possible to align labels' size to their `texture_size` property. Precisely, whenever I change the `font_size` which would cause label's `texture_size` to overflow its current size, I would want to increase the label size so the text fits. Since labels live inside the `RecycleView`, I'm not sure how should I approach the problem. I'm initially setting `height` to `self.minimum_height` of the `RecycleBoxLayout` which I presume should be updated in the process. I noticed that I can manually change the `RecycleBoxLayout's` `default_size` during runtime, but not sure how exactly I should pass the `texture_size` of the label to adjust the size. I tried with `on_size` and `on_texture` methods to pass the property and use to calculate `default_size`, but things get really complicated and I always end up getting gaps between the labels. Ideally I would want the solution that uses some kind of binding of labels sizes/texture (similarly like I already have with the `app.fontSize`) so I would get automatic resizing because any manual calculations of `RecycleView` properties and it's consequential update significantly slows down my program in the end when testing on Android.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I haven't mentioned it, I'm only interested in the height resizing. Width doesn't matter.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kv = """
<MyLabel@MDLabel>:
    font_size: app.fontSize
    halign: 'center'
    # Using these settings would be awesome, but cannot make it happen.
    # Or there might be more elegant solution?
    #size: self.texture_size
    #size_hint_y: None
    #text_size: self.width, None
    

<DailyService>:
    day: ''
    service: ''
    
    MDGridLayout:
        rows: 2
        MyLabel:
            id: firstLabelId
            text: root.day
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color

        MyLabel:
            id: secondLabelId
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
            text: root.service
    
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'mainScreen'
    myRv: rvId

    MDRelativeLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDRecycleView:
            viewclass: 'DailyService'
            id: rvId
            rbl: rblId
            
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id: rblId
                default_size: None, dp(200)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'

        MDSlider:
            color: 'white'
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top": 1}
            min: 10
            value: 20
            max: 150
            on_value_normalized: root.fontSizeSlider(self.value)


MyScreenManager:
    mainScreen: mainScreenId
        
    MainScreen:
        id: mainScreenId
"""

class DailyService(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def fontSizeSlider(self, value):
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        app.fontSize = str(int(value)) + 'dp'
        self.myRv.refresh_from_data()
    
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MyApp(MDApp):
    fontSize = StringProperty('20dp')
    
    def on_start(self):
        data = []
        for i in range(10):
            data.append({'day': 'DAY\nDAY',
                         'service': 'SERVICE\nSERVICE'})
        self.root.ids.mainScreenId.myRv.data = data

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = 'Amber'
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kv = """
<MyLabel@MDLabel>:
    font_size: app.fontSize
    halign: 'center'
    # Using these settings would be awesome, but cannot make it happen.
    # Or there might be more elegant solution?
    #size: self.texture_size
    #size_hint_y: None
    #text_size: self.width, None
    

<DailyService>:
    day: ''
    service: ''
    
    MDGridLayout:
        rows: 2
        size_hint_y:None
        height:app.MyHeight
        MyLabel:
            id: firstLabelId
            text: root.day
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color

        MyLabel:
            id: secondLabelId
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
            text: root.service
    
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'mainScreen'
    myRv: rvId

    MDRelativeLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDRecycleView:
            viewclass: 'DailyService'
            id: rvId
            rbl: rblId
            
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id: rblId
                default_size: None, app.MyHeight
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'

        MDSlider:
            color: 'white'
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top": 1}
            min: 10
            value: 20
            max: 150
            on_value_normalized: root.fontSizeSlider(self.value)


MyScreenManager:
    mainScreen: mainScreenId
        
    MainScreen:
        id: mainScreenId
"""

class DailyService(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def fontSizeSlider(self, value):
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        app.fontSize = str(int(value)) + 'dp'
        app.MyHeight = str(  int(value) * 10 ) + 'dp'
        self.myRv.refresh_from_data()
    
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MyApp(MDApp):
    fontSize = StringProperty('20dp')
    MyHeight = StringProperty('200dp')
    def on_start(self):
        data = []
        for i in range(10):
            data.append({'day': 'DAY\nDAY',
                         'service': 'SERVICE\nSERVICE'})
        self.root.ids.mainScreenId.myRv.data = data

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = 'Amber'
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Great solution! How did you come up with multiplying with the number 10?

Comment: Notice that I put     fontSize=20 and MyHeight = 200  and 200/20=10  When I put *10 it will grow appropriately

Comment: I hope you have understood me

Comment: I see now, makes sense. Do you know maybe does this ratio of height and font_size does well on Android?

Comment: I see now, makes sense. Do you know maybe does this ratio of height and font_size does well on Android?

Comment: No, I did not know this